# Adding description between Section in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Just wanted to ask you if there is an easy way to add description text between sections in UITableViewController ?
You can take a look at what I want to do in "Settings > General > Keyboard" in your iPhone/iPod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section footers are often used for descriptions. So, implement the following `UITableViewDataSource` method in your subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

For more information [see the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW13).

Comment: Thanks. I checked and just saw that it was:
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section